# Can Java be run without a Java Virtual Machine?

Tags: java

Sorry for the stupid question, I'm just beginning to learn Java. Can it be compiled into a .exe to be run on another computer, or is it only for computers with a JVM?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338724/is-it-possible-to-run-an-executable-jar-file-on-a-machine-without-installing-java

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/java/

Comment: The gcc.gnu.org/java web page hasn't had an update in 2 years, and when I tried it back then it didn't handle Swing or a bunch of other things.

Comment: Doesn't Java by definition require the JVM?

Comment: Java runs on more machines than an EXE does.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, How is that possible if you need a JVM for Java but not for an exe?

Comment: @Walkerneo: for an exe you need a whole Windows operating system while just a JVM is sufficient on Unix/Mac/Smartphones/etc (and is often already embedded/preinstalled in many of the machines nowadays; at least, the coverage of JVM is higher than coverage of Windows).

Comment: @Walkerneo, Because Oracle(Sun) provide a JVM implementation for every industry architecture. If a system isn't large enough to get Oracle's attention, then it is possible for the system developer to adapt or build a JVM from the JLS. Notably, Apple was typically behind in JVM version since they performed secret specific modifications to the JVM Sun supplied and didn't want to share, meanwhile Microsoft was prohibited from modifying the Windows JVM after they tried to roll a Windows specific Java language J++.

Comment: I didn't realize exes only ran on Windows. I really need to expand my horizons. How do you make an application that works on windows, mac, and linux then? If I wanted to make a simple text editor, what language would I use? What would the extension be?

Comment: @Walkerneo exes don't "only run on Windows". Exes are compiled for a specific architecture and only run on OS that support that architecture. Typically, this means that exes are compiled for individual operating systems. So if you compile an exe for Windows, it will run on Windows, and not Linux (unless, of course, you run it under a WINdows Emulator...)

Comment: What about something like Itunes though? That works on both platforms quite well. There are different downloads, but does that mean they rewrite it for each?

Comment: *"How do you make an application that works on windows, mac, and linux then?"* Write it in C and build that for each platform, or use Java. For the Java app., install/launch it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  *"If I wanted to make a simple text editor, what language would I use?"*  Java is capable of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly. You can bundle a JRE with your executable, which is kind of like the same thing. Embedding a JRE is one approach offered by [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

There are third party projects that will allow you to do this. A free one is http://gcc.gnu.org/java/ . I don't believe it's officially supported by Java though, but it's also gnu, who happen to know a thing or two about compilers.

There is also http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html which is a paid product, but supports up to Java 6.

Comment: even it it seems to be compiled, it's still interpreted.

Comment: My understanding is that excelsior is completely compiled, not linked like gcc java.

Comment: There's also [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

Can you make candy without sugar?

Yes, you need to have a JVM (just the executing for compiling) to run and to compile.
Although, it is not necessary when trying to write just the code.